# Start >Run> "MS-Settings:(insert name)", Gives me "No apps are installed to open this type of link"

Tags: windows, shortcuts, file-shortcut

I'm on Windows 8.1 Core

Running for example

> ms-settings:defaultapps

Gives me "No apps are installed to open this type of link"
And wants me to choose a program to open with..

Also following this tutorial to make a shortcut for an item in settings,
https://www.computerworld.com/article/3218116/how-to-make-shortcuts-to-windows-10-settings-on-your-desktop.html

Gives me "The file (example) cannot be found"

I have not been tweaking this area, So I am sure my system is not *too* borked..

I have disabled search indexing but I do not think that is the cause..

Comment: Why do you expect this to work exactly? The article you referring to is about Windows 10 not Windows 8.1

Comment: Nothing I've searched claims this will work on Win8, only Win10

Comment: My bad ... lol.. silly mistake..  I found a list compatible with Windows 8  https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/the_ultimate_list_of_rundll32_commands_for_windows_1087.html

Comment: BTW, some of those Win8 shortcuts still work in Windows 10 and provide easy access to CPL items.